# UI thread and background thread use same Global variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want pictureBox1 to display the CurrImage in the UI(main thread) and at the same time CurrImage is to be modified in the background thread which takes some time to completes. When background thread finished processing, it should replace the old CurrImage to this new one in pictureBox1.

1) I get an exception 
2) I tried a different image variable in the UI thread whilst modifying CurrImage in background thread and it worked well.

How can I manage both threads to run on the same global variable?
Thanks in advance

```
private Image CurrImage; int index;
```

`private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {`

```
        index++;
        if (index >= images.Count) index = 0;
        CurrImage = images[index]; if (!bkGrndWker2.IsBusy)  bkGrndWker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        pictureBox1.Image = CurrImage;    
    }


   private void bkGrndWker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = Iprocessing.Colour_style1((Bitmap)CurrImage);
    }
```

Comment: Is this WPF or Forms? Is this .NET 4.5 or some older variant?  Please use question tags

Comment: I am using .NET 4. 
This is the exception I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"
Actually in the list "images" if I shift the index so that the background thread and main thread process two different images, it works fine. But if I make both threads to process the same images each time I click next, it only succeeds by chance . I have tried also accessing the UI elements from the background thread Invoke((Action)(() => {this.pictureBox1.Image = Iprocessing.Colour_style1((Bitmap)CurrImage);}));

Answer (score 2):

Simple: do not access the PictureBox from the background thread.

```
private int index;

private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ //      ↑
    index++;
    if (index >= images.Count) index = 0;
    var bitmap = (Bitmap)images[index];

    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    pictureBox1.Image = await Task.Run(() =>
    { //                  ↑
        return Iprocessing.Colour_style1(bitmap);
    });
}
```

See: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
when I added async I get this error - "Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and also for Task.Run, I get - "semicolon expected" error.
By the way, I am using windows forms in .net framework 4.0 and I am a beginner.

Also from my original post, I tried accessing the UI elements in the worker thread by using 
Invoke((Action)(() => {this.pictureBox1.Image = Iprocessing.Colour_style1((Bitmap)CurrImage);}));

But it still doesnt work.